# RegisterForRemoteNotifications override method not being called

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications, xamarin.mac

I have created an override for the virtual *RegisterForRemoteNotifications* in the AppDelegate, which looks like this:

```
public async override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(NSApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("This method has been reached");
            base.RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(application, deviceToken);

            var credentials = NotificationRegistrar.Credentials;
            var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
            var request = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
            request.PlatformApplicationArn = "{ARN}";
            request.Token = deviceToken.Description;

            await client.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(request);
        }
```

However, my method is not being reached at all, wherever it might be (supposed) triggered from. At first, I thought this might be due to the fact I was calling the *RegisterForRemoteNotifications* method from outside the AppDelegate, after the app had been initialised. But when moving the call to inside *DidFinishLaunching*, whether before Forms.Init or after, or whatever I tried, my override is not being reached.

Now interestingly, neither is the *FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications* override being called. However, if I uncheck "Sign the application bundle" under the Mac Signing section for the project, *FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications* is called, likely due to the fact that a provisioning profile is required for APNs registration. But why do neither get called with signing with the identity and provisioning enabled? All the permissions / capabilities required are there (I assume). *com.apple.developer.aps-environment* has been set to *development* in Entitlements.

Also interesting is the fact that *IsRegisteredForRemoteNotifications* does change whenever I call either *Register/UnregisterForRemoteNotifications*, but the overrides are not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Big Sur itself is the issue for the development environment, as it is working on a production environment. The solution is to either revert back to Catalina or lower, or attempt to test notifications with a production release.